# Ansible Loop and Update Dict

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to use Ansible to loop through a nested dict and add a new key:value.  I'm able to add a value using combine to the top-level dict but unsure how to update the value dict. I see that loop can be used to iterate through the dict but how can update be done at the same time?

**My Dict**

```
{'host-a': {'os': 'Linux', 'port': '22', 'status': 'Running'},
 'host-b': {'os': 'Linux', 'port': '22', 'status': 'Running'},
 'host-c': {'os': 'Linux', 'port': '22', 'status': 'Running'}}
```

I'm able to append to the top level dict but not sure how to loop through and another key:value to the nested dict list.

```
tasks:
 - name: Iterate and update dict
   set_fact:
     my_dict: '{{my_dict|combine({"location": "building-a"})}}'
 - debug: var=my_dict
```

**Desired Dict after update:**

```
{'host-a': {'os': 'Linux', 'port': '22', 'status': 'Running', 'location': 'building-a'},
 'host-b': {'os': 'Linux', 'port': '22', 'status': 'Running', 'location': 'building-a'},
 'host-c': {'os': 'Linux', 'port': '22', 'status': 'Running', 'location': 'building-a'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the `recursive` argument to the `combine` filter, like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_dict:
      host-a: {'os': 'Linux', 'port': '22', 'status': 'Running'}
      host-b: {'os': 'Linux', 'port': '22', 'status': 'Running'}
      host-c: {'os': 'Linux', 'port': '22', 'status': 'Running'}

  tasks:
    - name: update dict
      set_fact:
        my_dict: "{{ my_dict|combine({item: {'location': 'building-a'}}, recursive=true) }}"
      loop: "{{ my_dict|list }}"

    - debug:
        var: my_dict
```

The above playbook will output:

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [update dict] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=host-a)
ok: [localhost] => (item=host-b)
ok: [localhost] => (item=host-c)

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_dict": {
        "host-a": {
            "location": "building-a",
            "os": "Linux",
            "port": "22",
            "status": "Running"
        },
        "host-b": {
            "location": "building-a",
            "os": "Linux",
            "port": "22",
            "status": "Running"
        },
        "host-c": {
            "location": "building-a",
            "os": "Linux",
            "port": "22",
            "status": "Running"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: @larks, This worked wonderfully. Thanks for the quick response.